# Printing custom usercontrols with MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, printing

I have a view where I display a bunch of trading cards. Each card is a user control, and these are all displayed in a window. There are 4 cards to a row for however many rows are in some observable collection of cards. I want to be able to print this. I have done this in the past by recreating all the UI elements in the code-behind, but I want to rewrite this using MVVM, and even though I could still do this method in MVVM, it doesn't seem to be the cleanest solution. Does anyone know a simpler way to achieve this? Here is my XAML code for the Window of what I want to print:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StateManager.Cards}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cardModels:AttackCard}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <cardViews:AttackCardControl />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cardModels:EquipmentCard}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <cardViews:EquipmentCardControl />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

            ...

        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="960"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As you can see, I have an ItemsControl that contains all the cards within a wrap panel with a fixed Width. The width of each Card is exactly 240, so this allows exactly 4 cards to fit per row. The Data Templates are for the displaying the different types of cards that all inherit from a Card class and are in an ObservableCollection. Any one have any ideas on how to print this? From my past program, I have also learned that only 2 rows will fit on a sheet of paper and it must be printed at a 90 degree angle (landscape view). Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not a complete solution, but answer direction: Printing in WPF is done by using the [DocumentViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.documentviewerbase.aspx) and it's respective `Print` method. Use one of it's implemented classes, like `FlowDocumentPageViewer` or `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. Either viewer just acts as a container control for various elements. For formatting reasons another set of controls are used, however the standard UIElement derived controls can also be used when wrapping them inside a `BlockUIContainer`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075799/embed-custom-control-in-wpf-flowdocument

Comment: Also have a look at: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/advanced-flowdocument-content/